I don't understand the terms "constant and trend" in the case of the Dickey-Fuller test, where the difference $\Delta y_t$ is on the left hand side
Take Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test or the R documentation https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/aTSA/html/adf.test.html
Type 3 Dickey-Fuller describes the model
$\Delta y_t = a + bt + \delta y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$
Wiki calls this "Test for a unit root with constant and deterministic time trend" and CRAN calls this "a linear model with both drift and linear trend".
In my mind, non-zero $a$ and zero $b$ implies that $y_t$ has an approximate linear trend, because $y_t - y_{t-1}$ is constant (plus noise). $b$ non-zero would therefore be a quadratic trend. So I'm confused calling $b \neq 0$ a "linear trend", as it's quadratic on the original $y_t$, or "deterministic time trend", as just $a \neq 0$ implies a deterministic time trend in the $y_t$.

The Dickey-Fuller Test with Constant and Deterministic Time Trend
The Dickey-Fuller test is a statistical test used to determine whether a time series has a unit root, indicating non-stationarity. The Type 3 Dickey-Fuller test model is specified as:
$$
\Delta y_t = a + bt + \delta y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t
$$
where:

$\Delta y_t$: differenced time series (first difference of $y_t$),

$a$: intercept (constant term),

$b$: coefficient on time $t$ (linear trend term),

$\delta$:coefficient on lagged $y_{t-1}$ (autoregressive term),

$\epsilon_t$: error term.


Clarifying the Terminology
- Constant ($a$):
In the Dickey-Fuller test, a non-zero $a$ (constant term) implies the presence of a deterministic level or intercept in the time series $y_t$. If $a$ is significant and non-zero, it suggests that the series $y_t$ has a structural level that affects its mean value.
- Deterministic Time Trend ($b$): The coefficient $b$ represents the trend component in the time series. If $b$ is non-zero and significant, it indicates that the series exhibits a linear trend over time $t$. This means that the series $y_t$ is not only influenced by its previous lagged values ($y_{t-1}$), but also systematically changes over time in a linear manner.
- Interpretation of $b$ as Linear Trend: Contrary to potential confusion, $b$ being non-zero does not imply a quadratic trend in $y_t$. Instead, it indicates a linear trend in the differenced series $\Delta y_t$. The differenced series $\Delta y_t$ measures the change in $y_t$ over time, and a non-zero $b$ suggests that this change is linearly related to time $t$.
- Non-Stationarity and Unit Root: The Dickey-Fuller test aims to determine if $y_t$ has a unit root, implying non-stationarity. A unit root exists if the series $y_t$ is not mean-reverting and tends to revert back to a long-term mean. The presence of a unit root would typically correspond to non-significant $a$ and $b$ coefficients in the Dickey-Fuller test.
Summary
- constant term indicates a deterministic level or intercept in the original series $y_t$.
- linear trend term indicates a deterministic linear trend in the differenced series $\Delta y_t$.
Therefore, when the test is described as "Test for a unit root with constant and deterministic time trend" or "a linear model with both drift and linear trend," it refers to the presence of these specific components in the time series model, focusing on understanding the nature of non-stationarity in $y_t$ through the parameters $a$ and $b$.
